# A Philosophical riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> When you have it, you won't use it.
> When you are using it, you don't know how you are using it.
> When you don't have it, you wish you had more.
> For some people it will run, for others it lags.

What is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's:

> Time

When you have it, you won't use it.

> Wasting time

When you are using it, you don't know how you are using it.

> You use time doing anything

When you don't have it, you wish you had more.

> I wish I had more time

For some people it will run, for others it lags.

> Time can run or lag

Comment: For some weird reason, I found your explanations funny, I have no idea why.

Comment: I was about to write the same answer, until I saw your nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> money

When you have it, you won't use it.

> Misers accumulate money for its own sake,
>  with no intention of spending more than the bare minimum needed for survival. 
>  Prudent people save money for future expenses:
>  retirement, children's education, and the unexpected ("rainy day fund").

When you are using it, you don't know how you are using it.

> People look at their credit card bills and say "I spent ***how much?***",
>  because, while you're spending it,
>  it's easy to lose track of how much you're spending,

When you don't have it, you wish you had more.

> Needs no explanation.

For some people it will run, for others it lags.

> OK, this one doesn't work so well.